# How can I uninstall Facebook Messenger for Firefox?

Tags: facebook, firefox

I have Firefox beta installed and when I visited Facebook the other day I turned on [Messenger for Firefox](https://www.facebook.com/about/messenger-for-firefox). I tried it and I think I'll pass. However, I do not see any way to turn it off. I skimmed through Firefox Options and returned to the Facebook "Turn On" page, but I do not see a Turn Off button anywhere. I can't even hide the Facebook buttons added to my navigation toolbar by dragging them into the Customize Toolbar window. The [Mozilla article announcing the Social API](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2012/10/22/help-us-test-the-social-api-with-facebook-messenger-for-firefox/) claims "It’s just as easy to remove", but offers no instructions on how to do so. How can I turn off Facebook Messenger for Firefox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To turn off Facebook Messenger for Firefox, first click on **F** (Facebook logo) button on the Firefox navigation toolbar (top right side). Clicking the F button will bring up a menu with three options: Show sidebar, Show Desktop notifications, and Remove from Firefox. Select **Remove from Firefox** to bring up a confirmation popup.

[image: Facebook Messenger menu]

On the **Remove Facebook Messenger** popup, select the **Remove Facebook Messenger** button to turn off Facebook Messenger for Firefox.

[image: Confirmation popup]

Answer (score 4):

Type in on the adress bar about:config, then search for social.enabled and change the value to false.

Comment: To be absolutely sure. I right clicked each social.* entry and clicked Reset. The icons in my navigation bar went away and when I checked the Facebook Messenger for Firefox page, the button was no longer enabled.

Answer (score 1):

CLick the Facebook "F" Icon on the top right of firefox, and there, on the dropdown menu, is an option to turn it off.

Comment: This answers the question "how do I turn it of" but not "How do I uninstall it" and should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off : Tools > Unselect Facebook Messenger for Firefox
Uninstall : Urn it on > Facebook logo in toolbar > Remove from Firefox

This will do the about:config thing without going into it (wich is /DANGEROUS/ for most of users).

Comment: For 'Turn off', it looks like 'Facebook Messenger' is under Firefox > Options or Menu Bar > View > Toolbars.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good guide from Mozilla http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-facebook-messenger-firefox-work

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.